# How to upload an image and get make it public in Google Cloud Bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload an image to google cloud bucket and get its URI(gc://my_bucket/file.jpg) using python.

Can anyone please tell me how to do that as I don't have any prior experience in python.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the easiest way I know of. It requires first installing [gcloud-python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python), which you can do with the command `pip install --upgrade gcloud`:

```
from gcloud import storage

bucket_name = 'name-of-bucket'
object_name = 'objectName.jpg'
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.get_blob(object_name)
blob.upload_from_filename('localImageFileName.jpg', content_type='image/jpeg')
blob.make_public()
uri = "gs://%s/%s" % (bucket_name, object_name)
```

Comment: Thank you. I was getting a 403 forbidden error when trying to use make_public(), but using it after the upload_from_filename call fixed that issue.

Comment: Please let me know if we can make an entire bucket public, if so how?